# Is this a good way to make a global context?

Tags: reactjs

https://pastebin.com/mUs0bnb9

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
 
export const TodoContext = createContext();
 
export const TodoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoArray")));
  }, []);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todoArray", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);
 
  let props = {
    todos,
    removeTodo: (inputId) =>
      setTodos((prevTodos) => prevTodos.filter(({ id }) => inputId === id)),
    addTodo: (inputObj) => setTodos((prevTodos) => [...prevTodos, inputObj]),
  };
 
  return <TodoContext.Provider value={props}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>;
};
```

Would this be appropriate use of the Context API?

Well, I did above code. Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: yes , 100 % - also you should consider put this component upper than other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, it is right.

Context API is very used, but the last projects we are using Recoil.JS, its more easy and better to work with, and its already in stable version.

We dont use too much Redux, Mobx anymore, so context and recoil is the best options.

Take a look in a Recoil documentation, and see if it fits on your needs.

Resuming, your context is right, but i prefer to use recoil.

Cheers !